# Convert Foreach into linq Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get list of devices against a current customer from a `Device` table. I did it but with a `foreach` loop, but I wanted to do it operation using linq, instead.

here is my class structure

```
public class Device
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
}


public class Role
{
    public int roleId { get; set; }
    public string roleName { get; set; }
    public int customerId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Code

```
var devList = list.Where(x => x.type == "device1").ToList();

foreach (var item in devList)
{
    if (item.roles != null)
    {
        var kss = item.roles.Where(z => z.customerId == kunId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (kss != null)
        {
            m.devicesList.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get devices against the current customer, so I have to compare my current user id with `customerId`.

How can I convert this to linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to approach this.

First, you could put everything into a complicated `Where` operation:

```
var devices = list.Where(d => d.type == "device1" && d.roles is object && d.roles.Any(r => r.customerId == kunId) );
```

Second, you could spread it out over multiple separate operations, but each operation is much easier to understand:

```
var devices = list.Where(d => d.type == "device1").
                   Where(d => d.roles is object).
                   Where(d => d.roles.Any(r => r.customerId == kunId) );
```

The performance will be similar for either option. There is overhead for the additional `Where()` calls, but not as much as you might think... the JITter can do some amazing things with this kind of code, and I wouldn't be surprised to see both of these end up with the exact same IL.

Also notice in both cases there is no `ToList()` call. You can very often greatly improve performance and memory use by sticking with `IEnumerable` for longer.

At this point, it's unclear to me from the question whether you are merely appending into the existing `m.devicesList` or whether these values can *replace* whatever might currently be in that collection.

Assuming `m.devicesList` is declared as `List<Device>` (or similar), the former option would look like this:

```
m.devicesList.AddRange(devices);
```

Again, there was no need to *ever* call `ToList()`.

The latter would look like this:

```
m.devicesList = devices.ToList();
```

We could also combine both steps into a single statement. Here's one of the four possible combinations:

```
m.devicesList.AddRange(list.Where(d => d.type == "device1").
                            Where(d => d.roles is object).
                            Where(d => d.roles.Any(r => r.customerId == kunId) )
                      );
```

Comment: Deleted my comment and my answer; missed the inner if check adding the item. Yours is much better.

Comment: Thank you so  much  for this amazing solution with proper explanation. @joel-coehoorn

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn This is completely unrelated but nice avatar you have there.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an object `kunId`, which is of the same type as `Role.CustomerId`. You also have a sequence of `Items` in object `devList`. And finally, you also have a property `m.DevicesList`, which implements `ICollection<Item>` (= you have a method `Add(Item)`)

Your current method checks every `Item` from your sequence of Items. If property `Roles` is null, you ignore the Item. If, on the other hand, you have some Roles, you get the first or default Role that has a value for property `CustomerId` that equals kunId. If there is such a non-default Role, then you add the Item to `m.DevicesList`.

I'll rephrase this requirement.

If and only if an `Item` has a non-null value for property `Roles`, and at least one of these Roles has a value for property CustomerId that equals `kunId`, then you add the Item to the sequence of Items in `m.DevicesList`

```
var itemsToAddToMDevicesList = devList.Where(item => 
    item.Roles != null &&
    item.Roles.Where(role => role.CustomerId == kunId).Any();
```

In words: the sequence of `Items` that you want to add to `m.DeviceList` is the sequence of all `Items` in `devList` that has a non-null value for property `Roles`, and has at least one `Role` in property `Roles` that has a value for property CustomerId that equals `kunId`.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to "implement" your requirements in plain natural language first.

What devices do you need? That ones which:

1. have type of "device1"
2. have role assigned with given customer

Construct each part separately, add necessary guards e.g. `roles != null` and you get something like this:

```cs
var devicesFound = list.Where(d => 
   d.type == "device1" && 
   d.roles != null && 
   d.roles.Any(r => r.customerId == kunId));

m.devicesList.AddRange(devicesFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove the .ToList() at the end of the linq expression value you're assigning to devList.

Additionally, if you're aiming to optimize the operation you're performing, you might consider maintaining the current code, instead of converting it to a linq expression.

Still, if you need to convert the foreach loop, have a look at the [official microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-foreach-linq?view=vs-2019), you should be able to do it automatically with the help of intellisense.

Comment: Please add some explanation about words about performance you mentioned.

Comment: @cly `ToList()` is often wasteful of both CPU and memory. Much better to write code to stick with the simpler IEnumerable, and save any ToList() calls for the last possible moment. Also, there can sometimes be memory allocation overhead for the state machine used with linq operations. If you have good non-linq code, it can sometimes out-perform equivalent linq, especially in memory constrained environments like cloud web or virtual web servers.

Comment: @joel-coehoorn So the code with foreach i used is better then linq query ? also better for performance ? Just because of number of lines i wanted to use linq instead of foreach.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Avoiding ````ToList()```` was trivial for me too. The statement about LINQ vs non-LINQ code what was interested to me. Dev team promises so much performance improvements in LINQ since its first release thatswhy it is interesting what you said about state machine and other things here. Putting some emphasis on "having *good* non-LINQ code" you certainly have right.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, thanks for the explanation. In contexts where memory management needs to be cirurgical, especially within micro-services architecture, it's key to be as efficient as possible.